# When I write .txt in after file name I get nullpointerexception

Tags: java, eclipse

Whenever I write .txt after a file name I recieve nullpointrexception error. But when I don't write .txt the program seems to run but it always says that the system cannot find the specified file. I have no idea what to do. Please guide me.
This is my code

```
public void signin(){
    //System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    File file=new File("C:\\Workplace\\3rdLastLab\\file1.txt");
    try{
        FileReader fr=new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(br);
        String text1=field1.getText();
        String text2=field2.getText();
        String text3=text1+"."+text2;


        while(sc.hasNext()){

            String string= sc.next();   
            if(text3.equals(string)==true){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are logged in!");
            }
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong user name or password");
        }

        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

And i get these errors

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Login.signin(Login.java:36)
at Login.actionPerformed(Login.java:122)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: which line is Login.java line 36?

Comment: Try `"C:/Workplace/3rdLastLab/file1.txt"`

Comment: If you identify which line in your `signin` method is line 36, you'll have a good idea what your error is. The problem doesn't come from the file extension, but from how you read your file, most probably.

Comment: I believe that the problem is there **regardless** of the extension. When you do not put extension, your program simply aborts **before** it reaches the NPE point.

Comment: Btw.: that '==true' is completely unneeded.

Comment: Please put `System.out.println(field1);` and `System.out.println(field2);` in your code right before you use them.

Comment: it does not aborts, it shows the message that is in the catch.

Comment: @user2382867 - OK. If you want to play semantics, *it aborts its normal execution*.  Anyway, what about `field1` and `field2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at behavior when you put the correct file name you get a null pointer exception

It looks like you have issue with `field1` or  `field1` ( if they corresponds to line 36)

```
    String text1=field1.getText();
    String text2=field2.getText();
```

which may be null depending on how are you setting these

Answer (score 3):

my psychic debugging powers tell me that either `field1` or `field2` is null when you call `getText` on them.

```
String text1=field1.getText();
String text2=field2.getText();
```

The reason you're only getting the `nullpointrexception` exception when you add `.txt` is because you're code throws a `fileNotfound` exception before that point.

You need to make sure that `field1` and `field2` are instantiated.

Comment: I'm with you here, but until OP posts more info we can't be sure.

Comment: @PM77-1 the op just told us where the exception is occuring in the comments section of his post, but it looks like he has removed the comment.  it was at `field2.getText();`

Comment: @user2382867 - I hope you have your answer now. If not - see my suggestion to print out `field1` and `field2`.

Comment: ok. field2 is password field may be thats why im having issue

Answer (score 0):

I am sure %100 that the reading process don't have any problem, because non of `BufferedReader` and `FileReader` also `Scanner` thrown to  *NullPointerException*.
I am sure you have problem with one of your text fields and I am sure that you didn't define one of them (maybe there are more than one), because  *NullPointerException* occurs while a reference data type without initializing. 
Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception) about *NullPointerException* .